# Converting SQL to Python Syntax

Tags: python, sql, group-by

[image: SQL Syntax]

[image: My python syntax]

```
select service_date, case when trip_line = '6' then '6L' when trip_line = '7' then '7L' else trip_line end as trip_line,
```

dir, ats_sta_id, hhpsbod, count(*) as act_thruput
from act_thruput_raw
group by service_date, case when trip_line = '6' then '6L' when trip_line = '7' then '7L' else trip_line end, dir, ats_sta_id, hhpsbod

and

act_thruput_count = act_thruput_count[['SERVICE_DATE', 'TRIPLINE', 'DIRECTION', 'RTIF_ID', 'hhpsbod']]
.groupby(by = ['SERVICE_DATE', 'TRIPLINE', 'DIRECTION', 'RTIF_ID', 'hhpsbod']).count()

I'm trying to convert this groupby statement to python syntax. I'm particularly concerned on how to include the count as a column.

Comment: that isn't "python syntax", but rather a library code that isn't builtin. What library do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

the database hasnt being specify...
But if you are using MySql or mariaDb mysql-connector will do what you need

and heres the basics of the librairy:
https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

Comment: Please post detailed answer and then references.